# Речевые ошибки

Tags: грамотная-речь

Недавно писал изложение с элементами сочинения. Скажите, почему в этих предложениях речевые ошибки:

"В детстве родители не привили своим детям сострадательное отношение к тому, кому нужна помощь".

В этом предложении речевая ошибка "сострадательное отношение".

И ещё одно предложение:

"Всё это поможет нам стать добрее и чутче друг к другу".

Речевая ошибка "чутче".

Comment: @Dima, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

"сострадательное отношение" - речевая избыточность, "сострадание" - уже отношение.

"Всё это поможет нам стать добрее и чутче друг к другу".

"чутче" - не речевая ошибка, такая форма есть у Ожегова, у Ефремовой, у Зализняка в их словарях - справочниках, но что коряво звучит - это да. Группа прилагательных с основой на -к с трудом образует сравнительную степень (хотя Зализняк считает, что это возможно). А простую превосходную - совсем с трудом. *Чутчайший - никак. (Или кроткий - плохо и кротче, и кротчайший). Я бы сказала "более чуткий".

А вот Слава указал на ошибку довольно серьёзную, но её почему-то учитель не увидел.

Comment: Я так хотел сказать о милосердии.Вот определение из словаря:"Милосердие - доброе, сострадательное отношение к тому (тем), кого нужно пожалеть.Словарь Ушакова тоже допускает такое высказывание:
сострадательный

сострадательная, сострадательное; сострадателен сострадательна, сострадательно (книжн.). Способный, склонный к состраданию, исполненный сострадания. Сострадательный человек. Сострадательное отношение.

Comment: Ну, значит, Ваш учитель "пурист", так называемый буквоед. Честно говоря, я просто попыталась объяснить, что она имела в виду, сама же за ошибку бы не приняла. Может, она имела в виду, что книжное слово не стоило употреблять, но и милосердие - книжное, а здесь уместно.

Answer (score 1):

> В детстве родители не привили своим
> детям...

= Когда родители были детьми… (???)

=================================

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Ошибки в сочетании **СОСТРАДАТЕЛЬНОЕ ОТНОШЕНИЕ** я не вижу. Так же как и в сочетании **"уважительное отношение"**, имеющемся и в БТС (см.  http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%F3%E2%E0%E6%E5%ED%E8%E5&all=x ).

А выражение **"сострадательное отношение"** употреблял даже такой знаток русского языка, как С.И. Ожегов.

См. http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/199342 :

> РАЗМЯГЧИ́ТЬ,.. 2. перен., кого (что).
> *Привести в состояние душевной мягкости, **сострадательного
> отношения** к кому-н. Р. чьё-н.
> сердце.*
>
> Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов,
> Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949-1992.

И http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/199346 :

> РАЗМЯГЧИ́ТЬСЯ… 2. перен. *Прийти в
> состояние душевной мягкости,
> **сострадательного отношения** к кому-н.*
>
> Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов,
> Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949-1992.

Comment: Я имел в виду не родителей.Как бы вы выразились?Ведь учитель всё равно  не будет проводить работу над ошибками.

Comment: Да просто убрать "В детстве", оно неуместно:"Видимо, родители не привили своим детям сострадательное отношение к тому, кому нужна помощь". А что было в самом изложении? Откуда оно? Из КИМов или сборника изложений?